# Python Input Driven Menu from Dictionary

Tags: python, input, menu

I am currently working on a script to list the Duck Hunting Limits by State, and I would like to add a `dict.items()` expression to search, but I don't know how to go about it. I basically want to be able to type in a number, for example "6", and have the function return all states that have a Duck Limit of 6. Any ideas on how to get started with a function to do so? I have included my current script.

```
# Please see following link for more information: https://www.ducks.org/conservation/where-ducks-unlimited-works/waterfowl-migration-flyways/du-projects-central-flyway

# Imports pyinputplus for input validation
import pyinputplus as pyip


# Dictionary of Central Flyway States and their respective limits
Montana = {
    "State:": "Montana",
    "Duck Limit:": "7",
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 2 - Jan. 14",
}
Wyoming = {
    "State:": "Wyoming",
    "Duck Limit:": "7",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Sept. 26 - Jan. 8",
}
Colorado = {
    "State:": "Colorado",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 11 - Dec. 1 and Dec. 13 - Jan. 25",
}
NM = {
    "State:": "New Mexico",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 4 - Jan. 2",
}
Texas = {
    "State:": "Texas",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Nov. 13 - Nov. 28 and Dec. 4 - Jan. 30",
}
Oklahoma = {
    "State:": "Oklahoma",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "8",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 17 - Jan. 13",
}
Kansas = {
    "State:": "Kansas",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Nov 1. - Jan. 4 and Jan. 17 - Jan. 25",
}
Nebraska = {
    "State:": "Nebraska",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 3 - Dec. 15 and Jan. 6 - Jan. 27",
}
SD = {
    "State:": "South Dakota",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "3",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 11 - Jan. 15",
}
ND = {
    "State:": "North Dakota",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "8",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Sept. 27 - Dec. 7",
}

# Asking user to type name of state
print(
    """Please type Name of Central Flyway State for waterfowl information.
"""
)

# pyip module with a whitelist of available state names. Will return error if input is not whitelisted.
result = pyip.inputMenu(
    [
        "Montana",
        "Wyoming",
        "Colorado",
        "New Mexico",
        "Texas",
        "Oklahoma",
        "Kansas",
        "Nebraska",
        "South Dakota",
        "North Dakota",
    ],
)
# Function to return the result of inputMenu and call out the corresponding dictionary with it's key:value pairs
def statefunction(result):
    print(result)


# if and elif statements to iterate through dictionaries and print items
if result == "Montana":
    statefunction = Montana
    print(statefunction(Montana))

elif result == "Wyoming":
    statefunction == Wyoming
    print(statefunction(Wyoming))
elif result == "Colorado":
    statefunction == Colorado
    print(statefunction(Colorado))
elif result == "New Mexico":
    statefunction == NM
    print(statefunction(NM))
elif result == "Texas":
    statefunction == Texas
    print(statefunction(Texas))
elif result == "Oklahoma":
    statefunction = Oklahoma
    print(statefunction(Oklahoma))
elif result == "Kansas":
    statefunction == Kansas
    print(statefunction(Kansas))
elif result == "Nebraska":
    statefunction == Nebraska
    print(statefunction(Nebraska))
elif result == "South Dakota":
    statefunction == SD
    print(statefunction(SD))
elif result == "North Dakota":
    statefunction == ND
    print(statefunction(ND))

print("Please type Exit to close!")

# Final input menu to stop python from auto closing
close = pyip.inputMenu(
    [
        "Exit",
        "Please Come Again Soon!",
    ],
)


def closefunction(close):
    print(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't have each state as it's own variable. Instead, have one variable as a list that stores all the dictionaries.

For example:

```
states = [
    {
    "State:": "Montana", 
    "Duck Limit:": "7", 
    "Goose Limit:": "6",
    "WaterfowlSeason:": "Oct. 2 - Jan. 14"
    },
    {
    "State:": "Nebraska",
    "Duck Limit:": "6",
    "Goose Limit:": "5",
    "Waterfowl Season:": "Oct. 3 - Dec. 15 and Jan. 6 - Jan. 27",
    }
    ...
]
```

Next, I see you want to whitelist some states. It's good to have a list (like `whitelisted_states`) of whitelisted states. To check if the user inputted a valid state, you can loop through the dictionary `states` and get the state's name by using `"State"` key from it, then check if that is in the `whitelisted_states`. If it isn't you can throw an error, or let them choose again.

This way reduces redundancy in your code and makes it much easier to work with.

To answer the actual question. Again, you will loop through the dictionary, and get the value of `"Duck Limit"` key. Check if it is `"6"`, if it is, get the state's name by using the `"State"` key.